# Why can't asp.net dynamic button fire in loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I found this very puzzling problem which involves dynamic buttons.

Here is my method that creates the buttons:

```
private void CreateButtons()
{
    //Button outside loop works
    Button selectItem = new Button();
    selectItem.Text = "Hello World";
    selectItem.ID = "btn";
    selectItem.Click += selectItem_Click;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(selectItem);

    int ItemCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < BillDate.Count; i++)
    {   //Button inside loop doesnt work
        ItemCounter++;
        Button selectItem = new Button();
        selectItem.Text = "Hello World";
        selectItem.ID = "btn-" + ItemCounter.ToString();
        selectItem.Click += selectItem_Click;

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(selectItem);
    }
}
```

Now here is the problem,
the button that is created outside the loop works fine (event handler selectItem_Click only redirects page).

Why does the button not work inside the loop and why does it work outside the loop?

Comment: because the button doesn't exist on page load during the postback most likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the buttons in your loop have the same ID, since you're not incrementing `ItemCounter`.  While you could just use `i` instead, you don't appear to be using the `ID` at all, so you're better off just not setting it in the first place.

Also keep in mind that on the post back the buttons need to be created and added to the page in the `PreInit` event in order for the event handler to be able to run.

Dynamically creating controls, particularly controls that have handlers on subsequent postbacks, can be quite tricky.  It's not uncommon at all to need data from the request to be able to generate the controls, but to need the controls to be generated before the request is processed by ASP for the events to fire.  It's dramatically easier to create a template that you bind your data to, using something like a `GridView` or a `Repeater` instead, as it will be able to properly handle re-creating the controls before the request is processed while still allowing you to have a dynamic number of instances of the template.

Comment: Are you sure about `PreRender`, or were you thinking `PreInit`?

Comment: I see the solution here, the button have to be initiated in PreInit. However what if.. my dynamic button is created from a list that is defined by the user. At PreInit when I call CreateButtons, the list of buttons is empty at that point

Comment: @BloopieBloops Yes, I mentioned that that would be the case right in my answer.  That's why you should avoid creating controls dynamically like this in the first place.  Use a `Repeater` instead.

Comment: Seems like repeater is the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
     **Use the below code it will work.**

        private void CreateButtons()
        {
            //Button outside loop works
            Button selectItem = new Button();
            selectItem.Text = "Hello World";
            selectItem.ID = "btn";
            selectItem.Click += selectItem_Click;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(selectItem);

            int ItemCounter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < BillDate.Count; i++)
            {   //Button inside loop doesnt work
                Button selectItem = new Button();
                selectItem.Text = "Hello World";
                selectItem.ID = "btn-" + ItemCounter.ToString();
                selectItem.Click += selectItem_Click;
                ItemCounter++;
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(selectItem);
            }
        }
```